# sp_BlitzCache Fails When writing to Table

Tags: sp-blitzcache

I'm attempting to run sp_blitzcache version 5.8  on sql server 2012 SP3 with following parameters:

EXEC sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'CPU',
                   @Top = 10,
                   @ExpertMode = 1,
                   @OutputDatabaseName = 'Admin',
           @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo',
           @OutputTableName = 'BlitzCache_History'

This is throwing an error when inserting to table output:

Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Have you done this historically and the table already existed.  I tested first with 5.6 and then 5.8 and did not have any issues.  I realized I was on a different version, so I went to a 2012 version that matched yours and it succeeded without an issue.  I would recommend deleted your current table and try to reload.